# How to configure QueueMessagingTemplate ,with specific region, to send message to SQS?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, spring-cloud

I am currently using STS 3.6.3SR1 using Spring 4.1.4. Trying to test spring-cloud-aws for feasibility of use within our application.

Jars Related to Question :

1. spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure-1.0.0.RC2.jar
2. spring-cloud-aws-context-1.0.0.RC2.jar
3. spring-cloud-aws-core-1.0.0.RC2.jar
4. spring-cloud-aws-messaging-1.0.0.RC2.jar

Using aws-sdk-1.9.19

Here is my applicationContext file that follows the spring-cloud-aws  [starter page](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/).

```
 <aws-context:context-region region="us-east-1"/>

    <aws-context:context-credentials>
          <aws-context:simple-credentials 
                access-key="*******" secret-key="*******"/>
    </aws-context:context-credentials>

    <aws-messaging:queue-messaging-template id="queueMessagingTemplate" />
    <aws-messaging:annotation-driven-queue-listener />
```

Spring-cloud-aws's starter page suggests that the queuemessagingtemplate bean will automatically inject an AmazonSQS bean when using the messaging namespace. However,as far as I understand,  I am running into an error regarding conversion of the string value region to the AWS enum values REGIONS.

Here is the relevant logs :

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'amazonSQSAsync': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#23ea780a' of type [com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsyncClient] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#23ea780a': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.amazonaws.regions.Region' to required type 'com.amazonaws.regions.Regions' for property 'region'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.amazonaws.regions.Region] to required type [com.amazonaws.regions.Regions] for property 'region': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1034)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#23ea780a': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.amazonaws.regions.Region' to required type 'com.amazonaws.regions.Regions' for property 'region'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.amazonaws.regions.Region] to required type [com.amazonaws.regions.Regions] for property 'region': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.amazonaws.regions.Region' to required type 'com.amazonaws.regions.Regions' for property 'region'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.amazonaws.regions.Region] to required type [com.amazonaws.regions.Regions] for property 'region': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.amazonaws.regions.Region] to required type [com.amazonaws.regions.Regions] for property 'region': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:460)
    ... 34 more
```

Could someone shed some light on whether my context file is incorrect? I believe *us-east-1* is the correct way of specifying a region but am I missing something ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First upgrade your spring version to 4.1. Spring Cloud AWS needs version 4.1 of the Spring framework because it uses the newly introduced messaging API.

I think that your dependency versions are not correct because the error you get (*Failed to convert property value of type 'com.amazonaws.regions.Region' to required type 'com.amazonaws.regions.Regions' for property 'region'*) was fixed with RC2 (see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/36).

Last point, you should use the same SDK version as Spring Cloud AWS, which is 1.9.3.

Comment: Thanks very much. Issue was upgrading the amazon sdk version to 1.9.3.